# Django database migration issue - missing "Migration class" error

Tags: django, django-models

my models.py file,

```
class Dag(models.Model):
    dag_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=250)
    is_paused = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_subdag = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    last_scheduler_run = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    last_pickled = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    last_expired = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    scheduler_lock = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    pickle_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    fileloc = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)
    owners = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)

    def _str_(self):
        return self.dag_id 

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'dag'
```

my serializers.py file,

```
class Dag_api_serializers(ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Dag
    fields = ('dag_id','is_paused','is_active','is_subdag','last_scheduler_run','last_pickled','last_expired','scheduler_lock','pickle_id','fileloc','owners')
```

while giving the commmand `python manage.py migrate`or `makemigrations` this below error occurs . i have one db table in my models and i want them migrate through this command...here i mentioned last few lines of error messages

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 96, in handle
    loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
  File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 203, in build_graph
    self.load_disk()
  File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 117, in load_disk
    "Migration %s in app %s has no Migration class" % (migration_name, app_config.label)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.BadMigrationError: Migration serializers in app snippets has no Migration class
```

in models i am referring the table which is already there.

Comment: Hi @uthay - can you supply more code and information? This doesn't normally happen if you're using automated migrations - are you creating your own migration? Also please post the full traceback (not just last few lines) and it would also be helpful to post the Model code. Finally, this doesn't appear to be a problem with rest_framework as the db migration is a Django issue (DRF just reads from the existing database).

Comment: Infact stack overflow not allow me to post the entire traceback. i am creating my own migration, but for the existing table model migration also i faced the same problem.

Comment: automated migration means "-inspectdb" command for legacy databases you mean? am i right ? anyhow i am not using automated. the db i am using id MySQL.

Comment: @PhilSheard now it would be enough i guess.

Comment: thanks, the traceback is helpful but we would need to see the migration code you have written and ideally the code used to define the Model instance that you're trying to migrate. The traceback alone doesn't explain what the code is trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks @PhilSheard. i have shared my models.py and serializers.py files here.i want to know what is "Migration serializers in app snippets has no Migration class" means?

Comment: Hi @uthay - we still need to see your migrations file, where you have defined the manual migration. Based on the error ("...has no Migration class.") I expect that the migration is not declared correctly, and so that will be what needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Django docs for Migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#migration-files), specifically the format of the migration file. Without seeing your migration code (which you said in a comment you have written manually), I am guessing the migration has not been declared properly.

The error is telling you that your migration ('serializers') in your app (called 'snippets') has no Migration class, so the migration can't be processed. If you follow the docs and declare the migration properly then it might fix your issue.

From the current docs (1.11):

> What Django looks for when it loads a migration file (as a Python module) is a subclass of django.db.migrations.Migration called Migration. It then inspects this object for four attributes, only two of which are used most of the time...

EG:

```
from django.db import migrations, models

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [('migrations', '0001_initial')]

    operations = [
        migrations.DeleteModel('Tribble'),
        migrations.AddField('Author', 'rating', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
    ]
```

Comment: thank you ! the problem is with improper migration only . i deleted migration folder and tried, it works .but with some errors which are not affect my execution..(err.Unknown column 'name' in 'Django_content_type) content_type table can't be removed. that's why the error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

You should just delete the file 0001_initial.py file and run again `python manage.py makemigrations`

Answer (score 0):

Well, this error only occurs when you have had the makemigrations but didn't migrate the file yet and later removed that model class, so in order to fix this issue you need to go and find migrations folder inside that app folder and select that migrations file which you yet not migrated or recently fired! just delete that file and restart the server again :), i fixed this issue myself with this way so this may help you too, its better rather creating a new app and doing migrations.